# How to supply an OLED module with 13V?

Tags: boost, led-driver, display, switching-regulator, oled

I have an OLED module that uses 3V for logic signals and 13V for the LEDs.

What is the common way to drive the 13V for OLEDs? With a regulator or some kind of special LED driver?

I have seen some LED drivers that have the feature "constant current". Is this necessary for an OLED display?
Or is it just the voltage and max Iout that is the important factor?

Do any industry-standard components exist for this kind of application?

p.s.
I have a datasheet but I can´t see how to add it, but I start with an printscreen at least.

[image: datasheet]
[image: datasheet]
[image: datasheet]

Comment: You don't say which module it is. If the module needs 13V to work, it does not really care how the 13V is made, so how to make 13V depends on how much current it needs and what voltages there are available to make it. You might get better answers by providing more info.

Comment: Many display modules have high voltage converter implemented. Are you sure yours came without?

Comment: true. I added printscrren from datasheet. I don´t know how to upload this datasheet here in the forum. Yes. This comes without converter. Uses a SSD1309 driver btw.

Comment: This is a Alibaba-display and is sold under many diffrent partnumbers.

Comment: @jora Datasheet page is enough, but it will be still hard to answer how to make about 60mA of 13V, without knowing if you want to make that from 2V source or 20V source, and if there are other importand parts of the design we don't know.

Comment: oh sorry. I want to make it from 3.3V

Comment: Since you want about 4x increase in voltage this is probably a good use for a boost converter.